# JSF Bean property not updated

Tags: java, jsf, cdi

I have a bean with a field called 'name', and a JSF form that has an inputText mapped with this field. The initial value of the field is well displayed on the form.

The problem is when I submit the form, the value is not updated with the content of the inputText. In the savePlayer() method below, the value of name is always 'name', not what I typed inside the form input.

The bean :

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class PlayerForm {

    @Inject
    private PlayerRepository playerRepository;

    private String name = "name";


    public String savePlayer(){
        Player player = new Player();
        player.setName(name);
        playerRepository.savePlayer(player);
        return "saveUserOk";
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

The form :

```
   <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{playerForm.name}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{playerForm.savePlayer}" />
    </h:form>
```

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can happen if you imported `@RequestScoped` from the package [`javax.faces.bean`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/RequestScoped.html) (JSF) instead of from [`javax.enterprise.context`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html) (CDI). Every single EL expression `#{}` would then create a brand new and completely separate instance of the bean. The given form example would then end up in two instances of the bean, one where the name is set and another where the action is invoked.

The `javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped` annotation can only be used in conjunction with JSF's own [`@ManagedBean`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) annotation not with CDI's [`@Named`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Named.html) annotation.

Comment: That is exactly what I did ^^ Thank you very much for these clear explanations :)

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, the symptoms are the same if you used `@ManagedBean` from JSF with `@RequestScoped` from CDI (or any other scope). Also here, the bean ends up in the default "none" scope and every single EL expression `#{}` gets its own instance.

Comment: BalusC, you are very quickly becoming my best friend on the internet for JSF programming.  Is there anything like `ViewScoped` for `@Named` beans, or is it better just to use `@ManagedBean` instead?

Comment: @BaileyS: JSF 2.2 has a CDI compatible `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`. If you can't upgrade to JSF 2.2 yet, consider using JSF utility library OmniFaces. Since version 1.6, it features a JSF 2.0/2.1 targeted CDI compatible `org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped`. http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped

Comment: @BalusC,  I am using JSF 2.2 and have updated all of my `ViewScoped` things to use the `view.ViewScoped` annotation.  This question and answer really opened my eyes to the hidden hazards of using scopes from the wrong package.